# Convert a region of each PDF page to grayscale

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a PDF that I want to print and a small region of each page has a thick rainbow at the left border. It is on each page. In order to save color ressources I would like to convert only this region to grayscale - or remove it completely with a white rectangle. I have looked into imagemagick but could not find a suitable solution to keep all the other color on the pages.

I have also thought of exporting each page to a separate PDF, apply a rectangle filter to each pdf and then combine it again. But I would prefer a simpler approach as the quality of the graphs seem to decrease each time I convert a pdf.

Comment: I think you have to do your second approach if you use ImageMagick. But note that ImageMagick will rasterize the PDF so your final PDF will no longer be a purely vector file. But you do not have to export one page at a time. I think you can do that all at once, if you apply the rectangle to every page of the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to extract each page to do that in ImageMagick. You can process it all in one command. Here is an example.

Create PDF:

```
convert lena.jpg mandril3.jpg zelda1.jpg test.pdf
```

[image]

Create white image:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:white white.png
```

Apply white image to every page of PDF:

```
convert test.pdf null: white.png -geometry +50+50 -layers composite result.pdf
```

[image]